# A translation for the clair french word?

Tags: translation, french

What could be the translation for the "clair" word in English?
I mean "clair" in the sense decrypted, not clear.
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Then I do not understand what you mean. Do you mean like cleartext vs ciphertext?

Comment: I think the translation that I'm searching is cleartext

Comment: Did you attempt looking this up in a translation dictionary (to se if the 'encryption' meaning is used)? Did you try google translate (which, if not always reliable, can at least give a start)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, the phrase *en clair* is used to describe unencrypted messages, as borrowed from the French.

From the [Lancaster University site](http://wp.lancs.ac.uk/enclair/about/):

> En clair is a French phrase that translates to in clear, and is used to describe transmitting a message without encrypting it first. In other words, you would say, “Send this message en clair“. By that you would mean, “Send this message in clear (or cleartext)”. By contrast you could say “Send this message en chiffre“, meaning “Send this message in cipher (or encoded or encrypted)”.

Comment: Ok so the opposite of "encrypted" is also "clear", thank you

Comment: @TheDevKiller Yes, you could say "Send this message unencrypted" instead of "Send this message *en clair*".

Comment: Thank you, the translation I was searching is "Send this message in clear"